# How can I solve TypeError

Tags: javascript

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at SpinBox.addEvent (spinbox3.js:28)
    at new SpinBox (spinbox3.js:9)
    at spinbox3.js:68

I'm personally studying development.
I tried to make a class and refer to the method.
But the problem continues to arise and cannot be solved.
I don't know the problem when the error is repeated as an undefined function or can't read property.

```
class SpinBox{
  constructor(element, value, min, max) {
    this.init(element, value, min, max)
    this.addEvent()
  }

  init(element, val, min, max) {
    this.upButton = element.querySelector('.plus-button');
    this.dwButton = element.querySelector('.minus-button');
    this.textInput = element.querySelector('.text-box');

    this.setDefaultValue(val);
    this.setMinValue(min);
    this.setMaxValue(max);
  }

  addEvent() {
    this.mousedownUpButton = this.mousedownUpButton.bind(this);
    this.mousedownDwButton = this.mousedownDwButton.bind(this);
    this.mosueupButton = this.mosueupButton.bind(this);
    this.focuseoutTextBox = this.focuseoutTextBox.bind(this);

    this.upButton.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedownUpButton);
    this.dwButton.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedownDwButton);
    this.upButton.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mosueupButton);
    this.dwButton.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mosueupButton);
    this.textInput.addEventListener('blur', this.focuseoutTextBox);

  }

  mousedownUpButton(){}

  mousedownDwButton(){}

  mosueupButton(){}

  focuseoutTextBox(){}

...
}

let spinbox01 = new SpinBox(document.getElementById('spinbox-01'), 200, 100, 300);
```

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for this script as it appears that you haven't initialised the properties correctly and with the little information that you have supplied it is impossible to help you any further.

Comment: @jeff What documentation? This is OP's code.

Comment: Seems `this.upButton` is undefined, so maybe check that `element.querySelector('.plus-button');` returns a value, or that the class `plus-button` actually exists.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: One or more of your `querySelector`s inside your `init` method isn't finding a valid DOM node. Remember that when you use `element` like that it means it only searches html elements that are nested inside `document.getElementById('spinbox-01')`. Try doing `document.querySelector('.plus-button')` instead of using `element` and see if you get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "element" to "document" for all of the below:

```
this.upButton = element.querySelector('.plus-button');
    this.dwButton = element.querySelector('.minus-button');
    this.textInput = element.querySelector('.text-box');
```

You are trying to search the document or window for the element.